# mipmap/ic_launcher.png still required for SDK >=26?

Tags: android, android-launcher

In Android there are 2 ways for specifying launcher icons (the app icon so to speak) :

**'old' way**

Specifying different png files in the mipmap folder typically named ic_launcher.png but the name can be set via `android:icon="@mipmap/appicon_android"`

**Adaptive icons**

Referring to https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.
Here the icon consists out of front and background drawables (refer to the above mentioned link for the complete description). Android says:

> Next you must create alternative drawable resources in your app for
>   use with Android 8.0 (API level 26) in
>   res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml. You can then use the
>    element to define the foreground and background layer
>   drawables for your icons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

If my app has :

```
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 29
```

Should the 'old' way png files still be included or is it enough only to have the adaptive icons present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it enough only to have the adaptive icons present?

Yes.

You must only account for your min SDK version. If your min SDK version is above API 21 you're free to use vector drawables instead of PNG.

Additional sources:

- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/vectordrawable-adaptive-icons-3fed3d3205b5

Comment: Do we still need the "mipmap-anydpi-v26" folder, or can we just put the ic_launcher.xml (continuing the adaptive-icon) in the drawable with the other drawables?

Comment: No, it's implied when your min sdk is 26. Perhaps even Android Studio tells you it's not needed.

Comment: Confirmed. I just put it in the std drawable and all is working as expected.